# Why aren't the BASH commands in for loop working

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have a simple code which is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#LaTex code generator for figures.
ls *.pdf > pdfs.file
ls *.ps > ps.file

pwd=$(pwd)

for i in {1..2}
do
# var=$(awk 'NR==$i' 'pdfs.file')
 echo $pwd
 echo $pwd > testfile
done
```

Why aren't the commands in the for loop working?
The $pwd isnt echoed neither is the testfile created.

I tried these commands without the for loop in a terminal and they work fine.

My bash file is made executable by `chmod +x bashfile.sh`

What I am trying to do is this:

- Find pdfs or eps files and populate pdfs.file and eps.file with their file names.
- Step through row by row and grab these file names and append to $pwd.
- Then append $pwd$var to the include graphics command in latex.

Comment: The loop iterates twice for me, echoing to screen and file (though there's only ever one line in the file because of the `>` redirection).  What do you see when you run `bash -x yourscript.sh`?

Comment: If the file doesn't exists, he should at least see some error output.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is what I see: 
\` 
+ ls k2a-FreeBC.pdf k2b-FreeBC.pdf
+ ls k2a-FreeBC.eps k2b-FreeBC.eps
`

Comment: Then I don't think you're showing us exactly the script you're executing.  You should at least see an assignment to the variable `pwd`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, I am showing you the exact file that I've been executing. I don't know whats going on.

Comment: Your file works for me as-is. I provided an alternative construction in my answer to simplify matters, but you have some other drama going on: hidden characters, commands you aren't showing, and so on. Try adding `set -x` near the top of your script, and see how the shell is evaluation your commands.

Comment: Why is everyone making allegations of me hiding stuff in my script file? `:P`

Comment: Are `pdfs.file` and `ps.file` empty as well?

Comment: @chepner no, they aren't empty at all. They have names of the .pdf and .ps files in that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong, but this works fine for me:

```
for i in {1..2}; do
    echo $PWD
    echo $PWD > /tmp/testfile
done

echo "File contents: $(cat /tmp/testfile)"
```

This successfully returns the following:

> /tmp
>   /tmp
>   File contents: /tmp

Comment: Thats very strange. What OS are you using? Would that make a difference? I have Ubuntu 11.10 here.

Comment: @DNA Tested on Ubuntu 11.10 with Bash 4.2.10, but that should make no difference in most cases unless you have a shell that isn't interpreting the range operator.

Comment: I tried `set -x` at the top (after the shebang) but nothing came off it.

Comment: I copied the contents of the file and tried them in the terminal and they work fine.. what gives?

Comment: Did you create your script using an Windows editor? Does the script have \r\n line-endings? `dos2unix myScript` may help. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you write the bash file using a Windows editor? Maybe you have a problem with line terminators. Try `dos2unix bashfile.sh`.